# Using a specific R with rpy2

Tags: python-3.x, rpy2

I have installed rpy2 within a conda env, using:

```
PATH=<path to R>:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<ldpath for R>:LD_LIBRARY_PATH

pip install rpy2
```

It installs without issues, however, throws the following error:

```
python -m rpy2.tests

import rpy2.rinterface as ri
  File "/home/common/apps/python/3.6/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
ImportError: /home/common/apps/R/3.5.1/lib/R/lib/libR.so: undefined symbol: drot_
```

**details of rpy2/R versions:***

```
rpy2                      2.9.5                    pypi_0    pypi


R was installed with openbals:
Installation directory:    /home/common/apps/R/3.5.1

  Interfaces supported:      X11, tcltk
  External libraries:        readline, BLAS(OpenBLAS), curl
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, TIFF, NLS, cairo, ICU
  Options enabled:           shared R library, shared BLAS, R profiling, memory profiling
```

Reading through (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-when-compiling-R-with-openblas-td4693330.html), thought it was related to openblas version mismatch. So I updated openblas, and re-installed R. However, I am still stuck with the error.

Here is a similar error in very different context:

http://lists.pgfoundry.org/pipermail/plr-general/2012-March/000640.html